# If $y=x^{2}$ then what is $\frac{d}{d y}\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)$?

Tags: calculus

Here's what I did:

$\begin{array}{l}
y=x^{2} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{d y}{d x}=2 x
\end{array}$

and we know that
$x=\pm \sqrt{y}$, let's take the $+$ for the sake of the example.

so $\frac{d y}{d x}=2 \sqrt{y}$

so $\begin{array}{c}
\frac{d}{d y}\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}
\end{array}$

But on Wolfram Alpha it gives $0$ because it switches automatically from $\frac{d} {dy} $ to $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.
But still$\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right) \end{array} = \begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(2 \sqrt{y}) 
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}
\end{array} $

I'm so confused by when can I take derivatives or partial derivatives.

Comment: I am afraid the question may make no sense without context. Classical Leibniz notation does not produce self-contained expressions, but heavily relies on the context.

Comment: If you put in $\frac{d}{dy} \big( \frac{dy}{dx} \big)$ without specifying to Wolfram alpha that $y(x) = x^2$ it will return $0$, as there is no assigned value.

Comment: @Alexey - that's pretty much the context, which is to check that if that's true or not.

Comment: @Dstarred - i indeed wrote that $y=x^{2}$

Comment: @ElieMakdissi, i meant that i am afraid that the given context is insufficient to provide a meaningful answer, but I may be wrong.

Comment: The notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ is *especially* sensitive to context. It assumes you have a function defined with the syntax $f(\ldots,y,\ldots)$ where each "$\ldots$" represents zero or more other variables. This doesn't play well with variables that already have defined relationships such as $y=x^2.$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $x,y>0,$ it follows that $x=\sqrt y$ so $$\frac{d}{dy}(\frac{dy}{dx})=\frac{d}{dy}(2x)$$ $$=\frac{d}{dy}(2\sqrt y)$$ $$=\frac{1}{\sqrt y}.$$

Answer (score 2):

By the chain rule,

$$\frac{d\frac{dy}{dx}}{dy} = \frac{d\frac{dy}{dx}}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dy} = 2 \cdot \frac{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}{2\sqrt y}$$

since $y(x)=x^2\implies x(y)=\pm\sqrt y$.

Answer (score 0):

When you substitute $x$ for $\sqrt y$, you also need to swap $dx$ for $dy$.